# How to search for two strings in one line using batch and then count the occurence

Tags: batch-file, logging

I have this project in mind, my goal is to achieve below condition using a batch(.bat) file.

Search through a .log file the patterns, "[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]"(1) and "Error"(2) in a single line and then output the total number of occurrences in .csv file.

Code used:

```
@ECHO OFF 
findstr /i /C:"Error" *.log | find /i /c "Error" >> Error.csv
```

Here is a sample log file pattern:

```
[2012-04-25 16:20:2] [INFO] [SAMPLE] Error in...
```

Expected output in .csv file

---

Here is the expected result:

[Time]
[Error Count]

1:00-2:00         125

2:00-3:00         45

3:00-4:00         246

and so on until 23:00-24:00

The counts of the string ERROR, which will be distributed under the column Error Count should be fetched/count the occurrence depending on the timestamp.

Thanks so much. I appreciate the help! :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's certainly worth spending a moment to review the [asking question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help).   I think you will see that your question is too broad to be a good fit here.   This is a place for _specific_ questions.

Comment: I was able to search for the string "Error" only. No luck with searching with the specified date. See below the code:

@ECHO OFF
findstr /i /C:"Error" *.log | find /i /c "Error" >> Error.csv

Comment: I suggest using the `/R` flag to search for a regex pattern matching the date.

Comment: @SomethingDark seems like its working now. I may have to tweak my code then. However, is it possible to create something variable for the dates? I don't want to be editing my code everyday to change the dates.

Comment: Agree with @GreenAsJade. Your question is vague. When I read it shortly after you posted I was misled by the title and thinking that this could be easily done with two FINDSTR cmds... one piped to the second. But as I read it again I think what you really want to do is search for one string ("Error") and count the occurrences of "Error" and display the time range followed by the count. If so the title is not accurate. What does the input file look like? If it is some sort of log file then presumably it is already sorted by date time?

Comment: There could be multi-line error messages where the string `error` is located on the second or third line of the message that you don't want to include at the risk of throwing off the error count.

Comment: Hello @RGuggisberg my intention is to search the particular timestamp and the error. for example I want to count the total number when the error occurred between 2 PM to 3 PM. The output must be the count.

Comment: Thanks @SomethingDark for the code you provided. I got the output. Also, is it possible to output in the manner below?

Time 01:00 - 2:00 Error Count 100
Time 02:00 - 3:00 Error Count 345

Comment: @Kristopher - sure thing. But since comments don't have multi-line capabilities, can you please edit your question to provide the example of what you want? I don't want to put everything on one line when you want each `Time <time> Error Count <count>` on its own line, or vice versa.

Comment: @SomethingDark I already modified the question to show the expected result. Thanks  again for your help on this!!!

Comment: @Kristopher I've edited the code so that the contents of the output file match what is described in the question. I would like to warn you, however, that since there are no longer comma-separated values in the file, it is no longer a valid .csv file but instead simply a space-delimited file.

Comment: @SomethingDark I have tried the new code, the output for the timestamp distribution is already correct. However, the string "Error" is not getting distributed per time specified. It just totals on the timestamp 1:00-2:00?

Comment: @Kristopher Yes, because in your question you indicated that the first line should be the string "Time Error count" and every line under that should be "<time> <error count>". If you want a different output, please edit your question to give the correct output.

Comment: @SomethingDark question is already modified. Let me know for any clarifications. Thanks!

Comment: @Kristopher, as you can clearly see in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YF3ZeyX.png), the output format of my code matches the output in your question exactly. My question is: _what is wrong with my output; it's exactly what you asked for._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost certainly missed something in testing, but this should be along the lines of what you're looking for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:: Proper regex would make this /\[\d{4}(-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}\]/g
:: Unfortunately, findstr regex is extremely limited and so our options
:: are either a short search string or a super long string
set regex_check_1=\[[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\]
set regex_check_2=Error

:: Search (the results of searching for regex_check_1) for regex_check_2
:: and output the results to a temp file for later processing
findstr /R /C:"%regex_check_1%" data.log|findstr /I /R /C:"%regex_check_2%">temp.txt

:: Initializes the error_count arraylike values to 0
for /L %%A in (0,1,23) do set error_count[%%A]=0

:: Searches the HH column of the timestamp and, every time a number is found,
:: increments the value of the element in the error_count arraylike
for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%A in (temp.txt) do (
    REM convert HH to H if HH<10 to avoid number being considered octal
    set /a hr_num=1%%A-100
    call :arraylike_inc !hr_num!
)

:: Output the data to the CSV file
echo Time Error Count>log.csv
for /L %%A in (0,1,23) do (
    set start_hour=%%A
    set /a end_hour=%%A+1

    echo !start_hour!:00-!end_hour!:00 !error_count[%%A]!>>log.csv
)

:: End the script here so that we don't accidentally call the function again
exit /b

:: Increments the value of error_count[hour]
:: This is a function because delayed exansion can only take us so far
:arraylike_inc
set /a error_count[%1]=!error_count[%1]!+1
```